# Dynamic MVC Controller with Spring MVC and Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Java 1.8 & Spring MVC (latest version) and I have a problem that I just cannot solve. I have a CMS powered website that has the content delivered to the web app by JSON stored in a couchbase repository. Each document represents a page and the key of the document is the URL of the page. So what I am trying to do is grab the URL from the request which couls be HTML or JSP or whatever and all GET requests through a single dynamic controller which will resolve the URL by finding the document based on the URL Key.

I have got a single page going through a dynamic controller but nothing else will for some reason and I can't figure it out. All I get from tomcat is a 404. Can anyone offer some assitance. I can do this very same thing in .Net MVC quite easily but with Java and Spring MVC it doesn't seem as simple.

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please post your controller code?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve the issue and I have posted my example code for Anyone who comes across this with a CMS driven website.

Controller Code

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @Autowired
    private ViewResolver viewResolver;

    @RequestMapping(value="**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView page() throws Exception {

        PageRepository repo = new PageRepository();

        String url = getUrl();
        Page page = repo.GetPageByID(url.toLowerCase());
        if (page == null)
        {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
        }
        else
        {
            config conf = new config();
            page.setViewResolver(viewResolver);
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(conf.PageViewPath() + page.getPageTemplate());
            mav.addObject("page", page);
            return mav;
        }
    }
}
```

Configurtion of my MVC Dispatcher Servlet

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fsdynamic.*" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="mvc-dispatcher"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Configuration of my Web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.eot</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.svg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future.